# How to number records based on values

Tags: sql, rank

I have the following data

```
FieldA   FieldB      FieldC   FieldD
1234     01/05/14    Mark     John
3234     05/04/2014  Mark     Smith
3232     05/09/2013  Kara     Sidney
3554     06/08/2012  Lamar    Angela
5668     01/01/2011  Kara     Rick
```

I have 15 Million Similar records in a data set.
I would like to create a query that would give unique numbers to "Mark, Kara, Lamar" whenever they appear to be their unique number.

```
FieldA   FieldB      FieldC   FieldD   FieldE 
1234     01/05/14    Mark     John       1
3234     05/04/2014  Mark     Smith      1
3232     05/09/2013  Kara     Sidney     2
3554     06/08/2012  Lamar    Angela     3
5668     01/01/2011  Kara     Rick       2
```

how can I do that?

Comment: No, It is not unique. there are no unique keys in this table.

Comment: You mean DBMS? It might not even be relational.

Comment: SQL ... I should use something similar to ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY FIELDC ORDER BY FIELDC)

Comment: the problem with that is that it doesn't assign a unique value. it reset the value each time the name changes.

Comment: sql is not a database engine.  It is a programming language that allows you to interact with databases.  Your suggestion of row_number() looks like it's worth a shot.  You should try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to get crazy, here's a solution:

```
SELECT [FieldA], [FieldB], a.[FieldC], [FieldD], [FieldE]
FROM [TABLE] a
LEFT JOIN(
SELECT DISTINCT [FieldC], pwdencrypt([FieldC]) as [FieldE]
FROM [TABLE]) b
ON a.[FieldC] = b.[FieldC]
```

That `pwdencrypt()` creates a *very* unique id.